# error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[7]' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arrays, function, integer

When I try to use my functions with 2d arrays, I get this error:

> error: invalid types 'int [7][7][int*]' for array subscript

I wrote many functions that use the same array. An example is:

```
void PrintWholeField(int FeldV[7][7], int i , int j){
    for (int k = 0 ; k < i ; k++ ){
        for (int m = 0 ; m < j ; m++ ){
            cout << FeldV[k][m];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Initially, the first size was left empty (I put in 7 because maybe then it would work - it didn't).

I wanted to test it like this:

```
int main ()
{
    int i, j = 7;
    int Feld[7][7];
    for (int k = 0 ; k < i ; k++ ){
        for (int m = 0 ; m < j ; m++ ){
            Feld[k][m]= 0;
        }
    }
    PrintWholeField(Feld[i][j], i , j);
    return 0;
}
```

But it gave me the error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[7]' [-fpermissive]

All functions give the same error, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `PrintWholeField(Feld, i, j);`

Comment: In `PrintWholeField(Feld[i][j], i , j);` you pass a single integer `Feld[i][j]` which is just beyond the bounds of the Field array.

Comment: thanks , that worked now but the machine(terminal) is empty did i miss smth? nvm the next anwser clered it up

Comment: `int i, j = 7;`  you set `j` equal to 7 but don't set `i` to any value. That will cause UB at any use of `i` like here: `for (int k = 0 ; k < i ; k++ ){`

Comment: `void PrintWholeField(int FeldV[7][7], int i , int j)` might be `void PrintWholeField(const int (&FeldV)[7][7])`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code as described below:

##### Problem 1

The problem is that `PrintWholeField` has an `int(*)[7]` as its first parameter but you're passing `Feld[i][j]`(which has type `int`) as an argument. Thus to solve this, replace the call with:

```
//--------------vvvv------------>removed the indices[i][j]
PrintWholeField(Feld, i , j)
```

**Additionally** the program has UB for **reasons**:

##### Problem 2

First, because you're using an uninitialized variable `i`. To solve this first issue, just initialize `i`.

##### Problem 3

**Array indexing starts with** `0` in C++, this means that you're going out of bounds of the array when you wrote `Feld[i][j]`.